# waypoint infinite scroll only adds more data once

Tags: php, jquery, scroll, infinite

1) I'm using jquery waypoint plugin and trying to do infinite scroll with php/mysql data.
I initially populate the container, which works, and then when scroll to bottom of page the "More" link appends more data.  But... it only appends one time.  I'm guessing I need to use a callback to re-enable or something?  But, total noob, don't know how to do this.

2) What is a good way to let load-more.php know what "page" we're on?  Just use a session var to keep track, or is there a way to send param from the main file?

```
div class="infinite-container">
<?
include("load-more.php");
?>
</div>

<a href="load-more.php" class="infinite-more-link">More</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/waypoints-infinite.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.infinite-container').waypoint('infinite');
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your problem is the same as mine then your issue is likely due to 'waypoint' not being able to find your .infinite-more-link. My "load-more.php" was returning a partial result and not the whole page. waypoint uses [JQuery.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to try and locate the more-link in your html, if it cannot find it then it turns off infinite scroll. The problem with this is that [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) only looks amongst descendants and not at root elements. I wrapped my infinite-more-link in a span tag and waypoint worked as expected.

e.g.

```
<span><a href="load-more.php" class="infinite-more-link">More</a></span>
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2WCwS/3/), remove the div around the anchor to replicate your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I also moved the "more" link so it's generated in load-more.php.
Doing that allowed me to do two things:
1) only show the more link if there is more data, and 
2) append GET page param, like load-param.php?page=2 and that took care of my initial question #2

Comment: Another solution is to replace http://api.jquery.com/find/ with http://api.jquery.com/filter/ in waypoints-infinite.js: Line '$newMore = $data.find(options.more);' should be then '$newMore = $data.filter(options.more);'.